# homebrew install script mac os 10.10.5

Tags: ios, macos, macros

Very simple script that installs homebrew in mac os 10.10.5:

```
iMac-phuocho:~ phuocho$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/Library/...
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
==> The following directories will be made group writable:
/usr/local/.
/usr/local/bin
==> The following directories will have their owner set to phuocho:
/usr/local/.
/usr/local/bin
==> The following directories will have their group set to admin:
/usr/local/.
/usr/local/bin

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort
```

it appears like this 4 hours .please help me.

Comment: What is 4h please? Did you press Return?

Comment: I do not do anything, 4h is 4 hours

Answer (score 2):

The script is waiting for you to confirm that you are happy for it to perform the listed tasks.

> Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort

means that it is waiting for you to press enter before it continues